# Wifi not working, but it's connected

Tags: wifi

I'm running alpine Linux on my e-reader, but I can't get WiFi to work. I got it working once, but after a reboot I couldn't get it back.

To ssh into the e-reader using the USB, I run this on my PC:

```
ifconfig <USB interface> 192.168.2.3
ssh user@192.168.2.2
```

Then on my e-reader I run:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
iwconfig eth0 essid NAME key PASSWORD
```

`ifconfig` gives:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:B0:D4:71:48:2C  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:37 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3908 (3.8 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:16:97:D3:84:43  
      inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:71707 (70.0 KiB)  TX bytes:37189 (36.3 KiB)
```

`dhclient -v eth0` gives:

```
Listening on LPF/eth0/58:b0:d4:71:48:2c
Sending on   LPF/eth0/58:b0:d4:71:48:2c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

EDIT:
I got it (kinda) working, I need to run all these three commands, and also in that order to get it working.

```
iwconfig eth0 essid XXX key XXX
wpa_supplicant -B -i eth0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext # fails, operation not permitted
dhclient -v eth0
```

The only problem I have right now, I can ping IPs, but not domains?

```
(none):/home/user# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=119 time=16.403 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=119 time=12.965 ms
...
(none):/home/user# ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
```

I think this is related to the USB connection between my PC and the e-reader, I can only ping my PC from the e-reader, no other internal IP. (It can't access my DNS server)

EDIT 2:

I disabled ssh over the USB, and connected using the IP. Now also the DNS is fixed, and everything works perfectly.

I still don't know why I need both iwconfig and wpa_supplicant tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifconfig eth0 up
iwconfig eth0 essid NAME key PASSWORD
```

This will only work if the WiFi network is configured to use the obsolete and broken WEP encryption.

`eth0` is also an un-typical name for a wireless network interface: are you sure this is the right interface? What does `ethtool -i eth0` say on the e-reader?

---

In the comments, the driver turned out to be `rtl8189fs`: an out-of-tree driver that might still be a bit rough around the edges.

Anyway, the wpa_supplicant is the key component for accessing modern WPA2-encrypted wireless networks.

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i eth0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext # fails, operation not permitted
```

The "Operation not permitted" might not mean that the command failed completely: the `-D wext` option tells it to use the old-style wireless extensions, which might not be available in your kernel. Once the attempt to use wireless extensions fails, the `wpa_supplicant` might try using a more modern WiFi control interface, equivalent to option `-D nl80211`. Try replacing the `-D wext` option with `-D nl80211` or removing it entirely, and see if the error message disappears.

Also, run `pgrep -a wpa_supplicant` after running the ostensibly-failing command: if it indicates that a `wpa_supplicant` process is still running, then it did in fact manage to continue regardless of the error.

Normally `wpa_supplicant` will handle setting the ESSID and the encryption key for you, so if `wpa_supplicant` works (as it seems to do, despite the error message), then the `iwconfig eth0 essid XXX key XXX` might be unnecessary.

Your next step is to find out why `dhclient` did not provide you with working DNS server addresses, and possibly try providing them manually to verify DNS connectivity. For example, try `dig google.com A @8.8.8.8` to explicitly send a DNS request for `google.com`'s IPv4 address to `8.8.8.8` and see the answer.

Comment: `driver: rtl8189fs
version: 
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: mmc1:0001:1
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no`
---
I don't know why it's eth0, but if I type `iwconfig` the nickname is `<WIFI@REALTEK>`

Comment: `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=eth0 disabled_11b_rates=0
eth0: Failed to initialize driver interface` --- the pgrep showed something yes --- If I don't run the `iwconfig` thingy it doesn't work, `dhclient` fails. --- Using dig works, but because I run pihole (it can't access ANY local IP) it fails. If I put an extra nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf, everything works fine.